# Create application to connect with computer

Tags: android

I want to create application which I want to use to turn off my computer. I think about connection phone with computer in WIFI. But I don't know how can I send commend to computer and how computer translate this commend and turn off computer. Can you show me the way how can I start and what I should to know to create application like this?

Comment: At basic level, You need to have some kind of application running in pc which in turn communicates with your mobile app and does your action..

Comment: You can use JADE(Java Agent Development Environment) framework http://jade.tilab.com.
In this system jade agent is running on each machine or device and it can connect to multiple agents and send command to each other.
Also refer following link - 
http://jade.tilab.com/wade/doc/tutorial/ExploitingInteractiveWorkflowsOnAndroidDevices.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with the client/server paradigm. You'll need to develop an android app that will work as client and a pc app that will work as server.

On the server side you need to wait for two commands:

1. Discover: Used for the client to know what servers are available
2. Action: Used to let the server know that it must shutdown itself

Comment: I think about connect using bluetooth. What do you think about it?

Comment: Wifi and bluetooth will work equally. Just take in mind that if you plan to launch an app to the mainstream not all pc have bluetooth so I wouldn't rely only on bluetooth. In this case support for both systems would be great.

Comment: yes, i agree, but when I useing laptop which is connected with other wifi, I can't create own wifi without loosing connection with this first wifi. In this case bluetooth will be better. So maybe I add two options: wifi and bluetooth

Comment: I don't understand why would you need a second wifi. Can't you just connect your android device to the wifi the laptop is connected to?

Comment: first connection is connection my computer with Internet, second is own wifi connectionphone-pc

Comment: If you connect the android device to the first wifi you don't need anything else. Both the android device and the laptop should belong to the same lan then, and therefore see each other